# How to sum values in dataframe until certain values in other column by group?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, sum

I have a dataframe:

```
id   life_day   value
a1     1         10
a1     2         20
a1     3         10
a1     4         5
a1     5         5
a1     6         1
b2     1         7
b2     3         11
b2     4         10
b2     5         20
```

I want to sum values for each id till `life_day` 4. So desired result is:

```
id    life_day   value
a1       4         45
b2       4         28
```

How to do that? I tried `df[df["life_day"] == 90].groupby("id).sum()` but brings wrong results

Comment: Are values of life_day, sorted by group?

Comment: @DaniMesejo do you mean in initial data? yes they are

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach almost works, but I don't know why you wrote `== 90` in `df["life_day"] == 90`, and it looks like you want the *max* of `life_day`, not the sum.

```
df[df['life_day'] <= 4].groupby('id').agg({'life_day': 'max', 'value': 'sum'})
```

```
    life_day  value
id                 
a1         4     45
b2         4     28
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the pandas where condition to mask and then groupby agg

```
df.where(df['life_day'].le(4)).groupby('id').agg({'life_day':'last','value':'sum'}).reset_index()
```

```
   id  life_day  value
0  a1       4.0   45.0
1  b2       4.0   28.0
```